# How to change markerTintColor in MapKit without changing default location pin in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, annotations, mapkit, swift4

I have MKMarkerAnnotationView to change color of pins on my map.

```
func mapView(_ MapView:MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?{

    let view = MKMarkerAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "pin")

    view.markerTintColor = .blue

    return view

}
```

But, when I start my app, marker of my defoult location changes to. 
How can I change pin without changing this marker?
Code to view location is also simple

```
 func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
{
    self.MapView.showsUserLocation = true
}
```

Thanks for answer! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could check if the annotation is the user location like this:

```
func mapView(_ MapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        return nil
    }

    let view = MKMarkerAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "pin")
    view.markerTintColor = .blue
    return view
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your method, check to see if the annotation object is an instance of `MKUserLocation`. If it is, return nil to keep the standard user location annotation view.

(The Docs for `mapView(_:viewFor:)` explain this.)